# How to copy 2000 images on server using PHP really fast?

Tags: php, apache

I have a PHP file (feature on the site) - that allows User to import data from his account on another site.
I also need to copy LOTs of images from there every time he wants to import data.
E.g. 500 pics, 300-500Kb each is minumum. Expect this number easily to be 2000 images for one user.

The steps for each picture are:

- Get the picture URL
- Make image from URL (by using imagecreatefromjpeg and others)
- Save it on my server (using functions like imagejpeg, imagepng etc)

It already takes VERY long to execute this code (over 8 mins).
I realize it's lots of data, but is there another possible way to do it?
Maybe run copying on background, or copy many pics simultaneously.
Just want to know if there is any technology that is designed specially for this, and I don't know about it.
Or there is no other way except to outsource work with images to some image hosting server and only keep thumbnails.

Thanks.

Comment: is the image on a local server or remote server ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's not a lot of information to go on here. What OS's are being used? How "remote" is the source site? What format are the images already in?

If the other site is remote (i.e., a different hosting company), the main problem you will have is the speed at which the source server can pipe the data down to your machine.

One big question though is "what format are the images in at the moment?". If the images are already JPEGs then retrieving and then converting into JPEG again will decrease the quality (albeit slightly). A better thing to do would be to just copy the image file directly. This will remove the time taken for your PHP app to re-encode a JPEG. Ask yourself - do you **really** need to convert the images?

Depending on what OS commands you have available, you would probably be better off calling applications which handle the transfer (e.g. `wget` in Linux). I've used `wget` to retrieve files from a remote server to a local one and it's not too difficult to get running.

Remember - the more steps you have in your transfer, the longer it is going to take. At the moment, you have:

- retrieval
- conversion
- writing

all handled by PHP (probably going from slowest to quickest)

Does the source host provide an archive or export facility for customers? If so, could that be utilised to transfer files en masse?

Taking as much out of PHP as possible will make the process quicker. Calling system functions (e.g., `wget`, `ftp`, `ssh`, `imagemagick` etc) would make things quicker still (outside of PHP *and* Apache)

Answer (score 1):

Threading seems to be the obvious answer ...

https://github.com/krakjoe/pthreads

I'm one voice in a sea of what seems like hundreds of people saying that PHP has no possibility of threading ... I think the current trend of turning to curl to do your threading for you is just poor, and to tout is as a solution even worse, the overhead of such things must be just horrible ...

PHP has always had the tools to multi-thread, it wouldn't be where it is now without them as it wouldn't have supported any multi-threaded web servers. It's just that it's not a design goal of the language, and the external efforts thus far to bring userland threads to PHP are unuseable, one was even non-existent on google code ... I require PHP to have threads for an upcoming project, so threading I shall have ... and so shall you, and everyone else, it is my gift to the world/web, enjoy :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Set up a queue of some kind for processing image imports - this way the user isn't waiting and scripts aren't timing out.
2. Try running parallel requests with [curl_multi_init()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-init.php)

Answer (score 0):

This is a PHP function you can use to download a file from internet ($url parameter) into a local file on your server ($file_path parameter):

```
function download_file($url, $file_path) {
   $out = fopen($file_path, 'wb');
   if ($out == FALSE){
      print "File not opened<br>";
      exit;
   }

   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $out);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);   
   curl_exec($ch);
   //echo "<br>Error is : ".curl_error ( $ch);
   curl_close($ch);
   fclose($out);
}
```

You can call it like so:

```
$url = 'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1f/Iss030e015472_Edit.jpg/352px-Iss030e015472_Edit.jpg';
download_file($url,'/var/www/www.mysite.com/public_html/images/image_user1.jpg');
```

make sure the folder you're saving the file into has write privileges for your apache user. Also make sure you have the cURL php extension loaded for this to work.

This function should be much faster than your `imagecreatefromjpeg` approach. Try it and if you still find it slow for you, you can improve upon it by implementing a queue to run multiple requests in parallel with [curl_multi_init](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-init.php) as Gabriel suggested.